# Speed up ImageMagick processing to re size tif Images

Tags: java, image, image-processing, imagemagick

I am trying to re-size tiff Image using ImageMagick but it taking too much time to process it. So I try to use ImageScalr but I am not able to change my image size and it prints just black image. Here is the link which I have use http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/#usage

And here is the code which I use to re-size image using ImageMagick

```
ConvertCmd cmd = new ConvertCmd();
cmd.setSearchPath("C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.9.0-Q16");
String inputfile = "C:\\TestImage\\Image1.tif";
String output = "C:\\TestImage\\resize.tif";
IMOperation op = new IMOperation();
op.addImage(inputfile);
op.resample(300, 300);
op.resize(2481, 3507);
op.addImage(output);
cmd.run(op);
```

1) If any one knows how to speedup ImageMagick process, please share

2) Else, if ImageScalr works for tif images, how can I implement?

Comment: Are you resampling image on purpose with ```resample(300,300)``` or just trying to set the output DPI? I think it would be faster if you would first resize the image and then set the DPI with ```density(300,300)```

Comment: It means, I am using two operations at a time which is causing time issue?

Comment: You first resample image (possibly making it much much larger as default DPI setting for images without them is 72). Afterwards you scale it to 2481x3507. Just comment the resample line and see if it gives any improvement.

Comment: I am trying to process 80 images. Which took 6 min 13 sec. after committing resample line, it come to 4 min 57 sec. It works but still this time also too much

Comment: I assume you are scaling those images down. What may speed things up is to first scale couple of times to only half the dimension as half scaling is ultra fast. Say you have image of 10000 pixel in width and you want to have 1000 on output. So you scale input by half 3 times, this will give you images of 5000 pixels, 2500 pixels and 1250 pixels. Finally from 1250 you scale to 1000. Maybe this will help you but frankly I don't know whether IM has this feature built in.